# Silex - check if user is already in database

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm new with Silex Framework and I tried to put a validation check when a visitor try to register a new account (about its username) to do not abble to save his request in database. I saw we have [Unique Entity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) in Symfony, but I can't import in Silex. I have been looking for a solution for two days now, but in vain

Comment: You can use annotation in silex. But @UniqueEntity is only for doctrine's entities. Are you using it?

Comment: @Federkun I don't use any doctrine with Silex, so if someone could told me me the equivalent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use Doctrine to manipulate your databse, you can [create your own constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

You can use it as a service, so you can inject your database connection into its constructor.